# VS2022 C++ empty directory for audio file. CMake; SFML

Tags: c++, cmake, directory, sfml

I did absolutely everything according to the instructions and it came out as usual, I read the documentation, this error is not specified, in the console in quotes should be the directory of the audio file, but it is empty, how do you understand it? I searched a lot on the Internet, there is nothing on this topic.
Visual studio 2022,
C++,
CMake,
SFML 2.6.1,
windows 11,
intel core i5 9400f,
RAM 16gb.

```
#include "chucknorris.h"
#include "Button.h"
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "SFML works!"/*, sf::Style::Fullscreen*/);
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f, 100);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    int x = 500;
    int y = 250;
    Button button(sf::Vector2i(5, 5), sf::Vector2i(5, 5));

    sf::Music music;
    if (!music.openFromFile("./ex.ogg"))
    {
        std::cout << "idi nahuy\n";
    }

    music.play();

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
    
    
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            sf::Mouse::getPosition();
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        shape.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(x, y));

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[here is the console, and the directory (which should be in quotes) is empty.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4kNO.png)

I want sfml to work properly and search for files in directories normally.

Comment: Never post pictures of error texts! What difficulties have you faced while posting the text as a text?

Comment: The error message told you to that the sound was not initialized and you need to call initialize() first before attempting to play sound.

Comment: What difficulties did you encounter when you clicked your finger on the link? @273K

Comment: The problem is an empty directory!!! It does not see the file, the program does not see the directory itself, in quotes should be written what file is not found, and in which directory, but there is empty!!!! @drescherjm

Comment: If the "" is the problem I suspect that you are using sfml that is compiled for a different compiler, like using Microsoft msvc compiled libraries with MinGW or vise versa or in the case of msvc mixing debug and release. All of these create undefined behavior because of incompatible ABIs.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue might be related to the path you're using to access the audio file.....

You have to make sure the file path to your audio file is correct. You're currently using ./ex.ogg. This means the program is looking for ex.ogg in the current working directory. Double-check that ex.ogg exists in the same directory as your executable or if not modify the path to where your file is located or just move it in the current working directory.

```
if (!music.openFromFile("./ex.ogg"))

{

    // Print the current directory
    char cwd[1024];
    if (_getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Current directory: " << cwd << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        perror("_getcwd() error");
    }
    // Print SFML error message
    std::cout << "Failed to open sound file: " << sf::err().last << std::endl;
}
```

this code will print the current directory and the SFML error message to help debug it.

Comment: note: Don't write things like *I think that* in the main part of an answer. That's the wording one uses when guessing, and an answer should not be a guess. If you aren't sure, don't answer. I agree though that I'd start troubleshooting by confirming that the working directory was where I though it was, but that's troubleshooting advice, the stuff of comments once you've gained that privilege, not an answer.

Comment: "Double-check that ex.ogg exists in the same directory as your executable" - The current working directory (CWD) is not necessarily the same as the one holding the executable.

Comment: Of note is that with Visual Studio the default working directory is one level BEFORE the executable with the project configuration files, probably to make it easier to use the same input files for release and debug builds.

Comment: In Visual Studio the default working directory is set to `$(ProjectDir)` which is a Visual Studio IDE variable that contains the path of the folder that contains the project file.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the problem is that judging by the emptiness in the quotes (in which the directory should be displayed) nothing is written, so I assume that it doesn't see not the file itself, but the directory, in other words, it doesn't perceive this directory, it doesn't see it